# Hosting a prebuilt Django website on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django

I have my website prebuilt on my local MacBook, and I want to host my app using PythonAnywhere. Going to the help page and clicking on hosting my own Django website takes me to the dashboard for PythonAnywhere and has no helpful information how to host my website. People keep mentioning this non-existant Django thing called "Whisky". I've never heard of it, and I can't find any information on it on Google.

Anyway, how do I publish my Django app onto PythonAnywhere? Are there any video tutorials out there? Thanks!

PS: My app works fine on my local PC, I just want to put the entire project on PythonAnywhere and have it work.

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoTutorial

Comment: That's for Django 1.3. I'm using Django 1.6 using Python 3.4.

Comment: Then check this out https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango

Comment: Again, I have my website prebuilt. This is for setting up a new website from scratch. I have my website made already on my PC, I just want to upload it to PythonAnywhere. I can't use FTP because I am using a free account for right now.

Comment: Upload you app to github or bitbucket and get it the zip with wget...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. After a lot of fiddling I found an help page. I still don't know what this "whisky" thing is (I know what whisky is, but I don't know what it means in web terms), but apparently PA uses "WSGI", which looks weird. But I've almost got it.

Comment: Yep Wisky is WSGI. You should may share also you help page for other people

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/ <-- Going here and clicking on the "I have built a web app on my local PC and want to deploy it on PythonAnywhere" button after scrolling down the page a bit (and after restarting my browser), a green box shows up. After about 3-4 hours of trying to figure out what it meant, I got my website working :D

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here, sorry we didn't spot this question earlier!  Yes, if people are talking about "whisky" they probably mean WSGI.  It's the standard system that Python web frameworks use to talk to web servers like Apache and Nginx, so Django is compatible with it, as are Flask, Bottle, Web2py, web.py, and so on.  Glad you found the tutorial eventually, if you've any suggestions about where else we could put it to make it more discoverable just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The really awesome Tango with Django tutorial has a section on deploying to Pythonanywhere - from using the console to setting up the WSGI file and static paths. I followed the Django 1.5 [tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/deploy.html), but it's in the midst of being [updated](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/deploy.html) for Django 1.7.